# Any words or phrases that mean "being jealous or envious but without letting it be known"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I'm really curious because I get jealous over certain things but I of course make sure no one finds out. but I'd like to know if there is a word for it. I'm jealous but I don't in any way show it. My voice or the way I speak doesn't change and neither does my body language (as far as I've been told).

So before I go off topic: is there a term for being jealous or envious and not  showing it?

Comment: Well, "secret envy" works, and is a fairly common construction.

Answer (score 1):

***Swallow One's Pride***

IdioMeanings says:  "The meaning of "swallow one’s pride" is:
(idiom) to accept that you must do something that you don’t want to do"

Thus, one might say "I swallowed my pride and congratulated Sally, even though she got the promotion I wanted."

Dictionary.com says:
"swallow one's pride: Humble oneself, as in, She decided to swallow her pride and apologize. This idiom employs swallow in the sense of 'refrain from expressing,' a usage dating from the early 1600s."

Another possibility is suppress, conquer, live with "***the Green-eyed Monster***".

The green-eyed monster appears in Othello by Shakespeare (as quoted in *The Phrase Finder*.)

"Iago:
 O, beware, my lord, of jealousy;
 It is the green-ey'd monster, which doth mock
 The meat it feeds on."

Shakespeare put the phrase "green-eyed jealousy" on Portia's lips in *The Merchant of Venice*

This reference explains: "Green is a colour associated with sickness, possibly because people's skin sometimes takes on a slightly yellow/green tinge when they are seriously ill. Green is also the colour of many unripe foods that cause stomach pains."

**Thus, you might say, or think to yourself:  I have to live with the green-eyed monster, but I don't have to let anyone know.**

Note to Editors, Moderators, whoever:  Should I split this answer into two answers?